# Merge arrays from multiple ranks using MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I have code that asks 3 processes to produce 2D vectors that look like this (increments by 0.05 on the second column), with zeroed values (not shown) for the rows that belong to other processes:

```
Proc 1
100,0,1,1,1
100,0.05,4,1,5
100,0.10,10,5,11
100,...,...,...,...
100,0.30,12,11,15

Proc 2
100,0.35,40,35,55
100,0.40,45,39,55
100,...,...,...,...
100,0.65,180,90,215

Proc 3
100,0.70,130,67,145
100,...,...,...,...
100,1.0,1,1,1
```

and I am attempting to use MPI_Allreduce to produce a 2D vector of the same size:

```
100,0,1,1,1
100,0.05,2,2,3
100,0.1,3,2,4
100,0.15,3,2,6
100,0.2,4,2,6
100,0.25,14,10,20
100,0.30,15,11,21
100,0.35,10,6,19
100,0.4,13,9,21
100,0.45,16,12,25
100,0.5,33,17,55
100,0.55,70,33,155
100,0.6,80,30,190
100,0.65,110,45,200
100,0.7,145,134,161
100,0.75,131,127,138
100,0.8,123,120,129
100,0.85,117,114,122
100,0.9,111,111,113
100,0.95,110,108,112
100,1.0,1,1,1
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
    // Function that calculates the average number of steps, incrementing over arraysize and probability
    // Output vector has 21 rows and columns represent [Arraysize, Probability, Average, Min Value, Max Value]
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> forest_fire_average_steps(int arraySize, int numberOfRuns, int rank, int numProcs)
    {
        int count = 21 / numProcs;
        int start = rank * count;
        int end = start + count;

        // init probability
        double p;

        // Create empty vector to store results
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> stepsResults(21, std::vector<double>(5, 0));

        if (rank == 0) p = 0;
        if (rank == 1) p = 0.35;
        if (rank == 2) p = 0.7;
        
        if (rank < 3)
        {
            // Iterates over a range of probability values, from 0 to 1 in 0.05 increments.
            for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
            {
                // Adds the array size and probability value to the first two columns of the row.
                stepsResults[i][0] = arraySize;
                stepsResults[i][1] = p;

                // Runs the forest fire model 'numberOfRuns' times with a defined array size and p
                // and stores the results.
                std::vector<double> runSteps;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRuns; ++j)
                {
                    runSteps.push_back(forest_fire(arraySize, p).stepCount);
                }

                // Sums the runSteps vector.
                // Could have used std::reduce which is more efficient but the HPC G++ compiler was out of date.
                int sum = 0;

                for (auto& n : runSteps)
                {
                    sum += n;
                }

                // Calculates and stores the average of the results.
                double averageSteps = sum / runSteps.size();
                stepsResults[i][2] = averageSteps;
                stepsResults[i][3] = *min_element(runSteps.begin(), runSteps.end());
                stepsResults[i][4] = *max_element(runSteps.begin(), runSteps.end());

                // Increments probability.
                p += 0.05;
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> finalResults(21, std::vector<double>(5, 0));
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<21;++i){
            int ierr = MPI_Allreduce(stepsResults[i].data(), finalResults[i].data(), 5, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        MPI_Finalize();

        if (rank == 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                    for (int j = 0; j < finalResults[i].size(); j++)
                    {
                        if (j < 4)
                        {
                            std::cout << finalResults[i][j] << ",";
                        } else
                        {
                            std::cout << finalResults[i][j];
                        }
                        
                    }

                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }

        return finalResults;
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure why but the output looks like this, where it has clearly skipped some rows (0.6,0.65, etc.) and added extra rows of zeroes:

```
100,0,1,1,1
100,0.05,2,2,3
100,0.1,3,2,4
100,0.15,3,2,6
100,0.2,4,2,6
100,0.35,10,6,19
100,0.4,13,9,21
100,0.45,16,12,25
100,0.5,33,17,55
100,0.55,70,33,155
100,0.7,145,134,161
100,0.75,131,127,138
100,0.8,123,120,129
100,0.85,117,114,122
100,0.9,111,111,113
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation that is causing this?

Comment: why the first two rows in proc3 have only 3 elements while all other rows have 4 ?

Comment: I also do not understand what the example input at the beginning has to do with the output in the end, i suppose it isnt related, but then what is the input for the output in the end?

Comment: Why do all your processes allocate enough space for the whole vector? That is not scalable. They should only have enough space for the elements that are truly theirs. In other words: don't store the zero rows.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout My idea was that by leaving space for the other processes work, I could just sum each process vectors to produce the final vector. Is this a bad approach?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Apologies, I've since edited this to reflect your comments

Comment: Yes that is a bad idea. One of the motivations behind MPI is that a big problem gets spread out over many processors, each with their own memory. That makes gathering also much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this program does not abort with a segfault. Your problem is in your definition of a matrix as a `vector<vector<double>>`. MPI wants contiguous buffers, and a vector-of-vectors is a bunch of small arrays, randomly scattered in memory. Write a class for your object and let it store a single `vector<double>` in which you index with `i+j*N` or so.